# Can I turn off IPv4 and just use IPv6 on my Mac?

Tags: mac, network, ipv6

Im really just curious to try IPv6 and see what happens. Is it possible to turn on IPv6 and to turn off IPv4 on my Mac?  If it is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: Just for my own curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: really just looking to see what happens. wondering if my ISP is up and running v6 yet, and really just how prepared things are for someone willing to use the new protocol. No real reason other then my own curiosity.

Comment: Did you give it a go?  Just curious

Comment: I did. i couldn't reach anything at all. Looks like i didnt get an IP assigned. The information under the IPv6 area was all blank after I set it to auto.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you're talking about on your Mac since you don't specify.  Yes you can do this but in all likelihood, you won't see much other than your internet connection probably won't work.  Most ISPs (Internet Service Providers) are not yet ready to handle IPv6 traffic and many won't be right up to [IPv6 day on June 8th 2011](http://isoc.org/wp/worldipv6day/).  Many won't be ready beyond then either.  But it won't do any harm to try it out if that's what you're worried about.  As an aside, the [last batches of IPv4 addresses were distributed recently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion).

To turn IPv4 off go to System Preferences > Network > Advanced > TCPIP

Then on the drop-down list next to 'Configure IPv4' select the 'Off' Option.  Then beneath that, you can set the 'Configure IPv6' drop down menu to whatever you want.

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant on my mac. Running OSX (updated snow leopard). How would I go about turning IPv4 off?